# How to swap two windows of the same app in taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, if you want to swap two windows in the taskbar, you just drag and swap the two windows. But if the two windows are from the same app, for example if they are both Chrome windows - you can't swap windows that way, as all the windows would move together.

So how do you swap two windows of the same app? I think it's still somehow possible - as a couple of times in Chrome I accidentally swapped two windows, without any clue as to how. Perhaps there's some key you have to press down while attempting the "drag-swapping"?

This specific question about swapping two windows **of the same app** has not been asked in SuperUser before, I believe.

Comment: Try <ctrl> and/or <shift> while dragging.

Comment: They do not seem to be working in any combinations, @DavidPostill. Maybe other keys could do the trick?

Comment: Even if you do not combine the "same" icons (Taskbar settings), they still move together. It is likely part of the overall design that allows you to combine "same" icons

Comment: Could try <alt> I suppose ...

Comment: Of course that we have tried all kinds of Monkey Tricks before asking, @DavidPostill. Neither the Alt[er] key, nor any other keys are working. It is however interesting that the human minds are always going beyond the initial ideas of the software creators.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I am asking the OP, Tony, not you, what he has tried. It is his problem we are trying to solve, nothing to do with you.

Comment: @DavidPostill <ctrl>, <shift> and <alt> doesn't work in any combinations!